# Alternatives to oracle flashback database/table functionality

Tags: database, oracle

Does anyone know of an open source tool or similar that covers the same functionality as the Oracle EE built-in flashback database and flashback table features?

I'm considering going from Oracle EE to SE/SE1 and these are features that would be nice to retain in one way or another.

An alternative could be emulating these features in SE/SE1 - does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool which does provide a similar functionality.

But there is much more functionality which an EE has and I would not want to miss.
For example:

- parallel execution, parallel query, parallel backup and **restore** (how long does it take to restore your db? can you risk such a downtime without the possibility to speed up??)
- single block recovery (ever experienced corrupt blocks in SE? -- not funny!)
- resource manager (for enterprise requirements you absolutely need this to handle the load)
- Diagnostic and Tuning Pack Options
- DataGuard
- Flashback of course

... just to mention a few ... you should keep in mind that an enterprise level environment needs an enterprise edition database. If your database is business critical and no one can work without it you better stay with EE.

OK, back to your question. You can build up a manual standby database which is always in mount mode and recovers the archivelogs produced by the production database. This standby database will just apply the archivelogs which are older that *n* hours so if you do something faulty on your production database you can stop the archivelog apply script on the standby database, open it in *read only* mode and export the data before the mistake gets applied on the standby db.

This requires:

- production database (of course)
- shell/batch script which moves the archivelogs from the primary to the standby database (not needed if it's the same host as the primary)
- a second database
- archivelog apply script in shell/batch script
- Oracle SE License (not needed if it's the same host as the primary)

I usually recommend this kind of solution as a replacement for a DataGuard. But this could also fit for you. But this will not replace the *5 minute flashback and flash forward* functionality of flashback. It will take some hours (2-6) to get lost data back.